# Xcode 5: has static analyzer clang by default?

Tags: xcode, clang

I have Xcode 5. If I click the Product->Analyze item in the menu,
does it mean clang static analyzer is invoked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that option will run the clang analyzer for you, but only once. You have to select it each time you want to run the analyzer.

To run it automatically, you can turn it on in the project compiler settings. The option is called `Analyze during 'Build'`. Then it will run each time you build the project.

Comment: a ok, I meant just to run once